# Does Camel's hdfs2 component support Kerberos authentication?

Tags: apache-camel, hdfs, kerberos

I'm trying to use Camel's hdfs2 component to read from a folder in HDFS, but my company uses Kerberos authentication and I get an error telling me that I need to provide authentication:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.getFileInfo(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771) ~[hadoop-hdfs-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.2.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.getFileInfo(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2108) ~[hadoop-hdfs-2.7.2.jar:na]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I couldn't find any reference to authentication support in the [component documentation](http://camel.apache.org/hdfs2.html).

I've got a workaround by using the jetty component to call [WebHDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.htm) and manually providing a token, but I'd prefer to use the built-in component. Is there any way to authenticate with Kerberos through the hdfs2 component?